# Facing ZIPPO_CONTEXT_INVALID error while fetching price or calling any other api on mumbai testnet

Tags: polygon, 0x, swaps

I am trying to call this endpoint on mumbai testnet using 0x protocol and getting the error .

{
"code": 100,
"reason": "Validation Failed",
"validationErrors": [
{
"field": "zippo",
"code": 1010,
"reason": "ZIPPO_CONTEXT_INVALID",
"description": "Invalid zippo context"
}
]
}

This endpoint is working for mainnet but failing on mumbai testnet. How can i fix this ?